# Adding SWF to HTML based AIR App

Tags: html, actionscript-3, air, adobe, flash

I have a little HTML based Adobe AIR project I'm playing with and I'd like to add an existing SWF to the project.  Now, I can see it running via the trace/log messages coming through from the SWF, but I can't seem to call any function within the SWF.  I've read that the ExternalInterface function isn't available within the Air container, which looks like the right thing to use if within a browser.

Most of the samples on the Adobe site are all HTML, or all Flex/ActionScript.  Has anyone tried to pull these together successfully, either as source, or through compiled SWF?

Many thanks

Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically was what I needed:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed9.html

However, my scenario was complicated in that it turns out my SWF had an embedded SWF and I was trying to access a class within the embedded SWF.  Once I tried to access a class within the wrapping SWF, it all was rosy.

Cheers

Robbie

Answer (score 0):

Using a compiled swf has sandboxing issues.

Maybe you can make use of LocalConnection? [Here is an example](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/01/11/more-fun-with-air-localconnection-source-included/).

Comment: Thanks, I never got to try this - I found an answer.  See below.